# MERN server deployment not finding static client files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my application using render.com free instances and the client side deployed just fine , however when trying to deploy my server side code I'm getting this error when i go the url:

```
{"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/opt/render/project/src/client/dist/index.html'","stack":null}
```

I'm using vite and the index.html is in the directory `client/dist/index.html`

this is my server side index.js:

```
import express from "express";
import path, { dirname } from "path";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import connectDB from "./database/db.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/usersRoutes.js";
import scoresRoutes from "./routes/scoresRoutes.js";
import { notFound, errorHandler } from "./middleware/errorMiddleware.js";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/users/scores", scoresRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  const clientDistPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "client", "dist");
  console.log("clientDistPath:", clientDistPath);
  app.use(express.static(clientDistPath));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(clientDistPath, "index.html")));
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Server is ready"));
}

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is started on port ${port}`));
```

I have put all the necessary env files into render.com and for
root directory i have it under `server`.

when i test the `npm install` and the `npm start` locally it works just fine when i go to my `localhost:5000`. I only get the error when i go to the render api url.

I was expecting for the render api url to show the message `Server is ready`